# In Ant, how to specify the source code to be compiled

Tags: java, ant

I am using an Ant script for building Java project. In the source code file, src, I have two files, test1.java, test2.java and test3.java. At present, I only want to compile test1.java and test2.java.

My ant script has sth like

```
<property name="src" location="./src"/>
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpathref="classpath"/>
```

This script essentially compiles all three java file. How to modify the above one, in specific,  to leave test3.java away.

Comment: Why don't you want test3.java compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a nested `exclude` element in the `javac` task.

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpathref="classpath">
  <exclude name="**/test3.java">
</javac>
```

See [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for example about how to use nested `include` and `exclude` elements to control the files that are built.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in the [ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) (look under tasks/javac). E.g.

```
 <javac sourcepath="" srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}" >
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
    <exclude name="**/Example.java"/>
  </javac>
```

But unless this is a throwaway example, excluding one class isn't such a great idea - e.g. you might have code in test2 that depends on test3 - this would then work properly in an ide but break in your ant script.